# How to do two ifs at once

Tags: java, 2d

I have a Background Image and a Hero Image. In the Background, at 520(x) and 260(y) is a house. I don't want my Hero to be able to "pass through" the house, but my methods aren't working. This is what I have done so far
(I don't know if it is enough information):

```
public void moveRight() {
   if (HeroX < 730) {
       if (HeroX >= 520 && HeroY >= 260) {
           System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
       }else {
           System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
           HeroX = HeroX + HeroSpeed;
       }
   } else {
       System.out.println("Da kann ich nicht weiter gehen!");
   }
}
```

Comment: oh and the "Da kann ich nicht weiter gehen!" means "I can't pass!"

Comment: What conditions are successful and what conditions represent failure? A good way to approach this might be to assign a boolean variable to each condition and then perform simple boolean arithmetic with combinations of conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The house is (i suppose) a rectangular or polygonal shape rather than a line, so why don't you simply use one of these classes to represent the house?

```
//import java.awt.*;

//change the type of house to Polygon, if Rectangle doesn't meet
//your requirements
Rectangle house = new Rectangle(/* insert coordinates here*/);
Rectangle hero = new Rectangle(/* coordinates of the hero*/);

if(house.intersects(hero.x , hero.y , hero.width , hero.height))
     System.out.println("Can't pass");
else
     //move
```

Answer (score 0):

you should ask if your hero + your hero movement speed  in the condition

if(  (HeroX  + herospeed ) >= 520 & HeroY >= 260 ) 
so you check he won't go throught the house before moving

Comment: maybe you'll need to rework your logic a little
as i see a bit of errors

Comment: you need to add another if inside your if 
also... try working the order of your code. im going to post you another answer so you can see

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void moveRight() 
 {
      if (HeroX < 730)  //i guess this is the border
      {
          if(HeroX >= 520 && HeroY >= 260) //this is the house at this position the hero should be already inside, so you have to rework this part
          {
               System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
          }
          else 
          {
               // here should be the error and also a second if when the hero is farther than the house length

               System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
               HeroX = HeroX + HeroSpeed;
          }
     } 
     else 
     {
          System.out.println("Da kann ich nicht weiter gehen!");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better i think:

```
public void moveRight() {
   if (HeroX < 730) {
       if (house.intersects(HeroX , HeroY, 38, 55)) {
           System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
       }else {
           System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
           HeroX = HeroX + HeroSpeed;
       }
   } else {
       System.out.println("Da kann ich nicht weiter gehen!");
   }
}
public void moveLeft() {
    if (HeroX > 0) {
        if (house.intersects(HeroX, HeroY, 38, 55)){

        }else {
            System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
            HeroX -= HeroSpeed;
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Da kann ich nicht weiter gehen!");
    }
}
public void moveUp() {
    if (HeroY >= 0) {
        if (house.intersects(HeroX, HeroY, 38, 55)){

        }else {
            System.out.println("X = " + HeroX + " , Y = " + HeroY);
            HeroY -= HeroSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```